# How to obtain second derivative of generalized Laguerre polynomials with sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I can obtain the expression for derivative but it doesn't work with n = 0, 1 because n should be >= 0 and in derivative there is L(n-2, 2, r). How to calculate it with sympy taking into account that it's easy to obtain it when L is in explicit form?

Upd: my code. So I cannot substitute l = 0 to chiLambdified.

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
from sympy.functions.special.gamma_functions import gamma as SymG
from sympy import assoc_laguerre as SymL
from sympy import factorial as SymFactorial
from sympy import exp as SymExp

r, l, beta = sym.symbols('r, l, beta', real = True)

def chifD(r, l, beta):
    return sym.sqrt( SymFactorial(l)*beta**3/(SymG(3 + l))) * r * SymL(l,2, beta * r) * SymExp(- beta * r / 2 )

def chiD(r, l, beta):
    return sym.diff(chifD(r ,l, beta), r, r)

chiLambdified = sym.lambdify((r, l, beta), chiD(r, l, beta), 'sympy')
```

Comment: What is `L`? What import statements are you using? Share some reproducible code please.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem here: the second derivative, with respect to x, of the associated Laguerre polynomials L_n^a(x) with n<2 is identically zero.

Comment: You don't know how to obtain the second derivative of a polynomial of degree 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0):

**Second order Derivative of a Polynomial of order 0 or 1 is ZERO.**
You can show it as follows.

```py
# Calculating the third order differential of 
# a second order polynomial: yields a zero
diff(3*x**2 + 2, x, 3)
```

Using `sympy` for calculating first and second order derivatives.

```py
from sympy import Symbol, Function, diff
x = Symbol("x")
dydx = diff(3*x**2 + 2, x, 1)
d2ydx2 = diff(3*x**2 + 2, x, 2)
dydx, d2ydx2
```

**Output**:

```
(6*x, 6)
```

If you would like to use a function:

```py
f = Function("f")(x)
n = 2 # order of derivative
d2ydx2 = diff(f, x, n).subs(f, 3*x**2 + 2).doit()
```

Another example using special functions:

```py
import 
Lgr = sympy.polys.orthopolys.laguerre_poly
Lgr(2, x=x), diff(Lgr(2, x=x), x, 2), diff(Lgr(2, x=x), x, 3), diff(Lgr(1, x=x), x, 2)
```

**Output**:

```
(3*x**2/2 - 1/2, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: It's zero, but I need to obtain it in my general expression. Of course I can just substitute zero into my next function (and I have already done it) but it's awkward, I'd like to substitute general expression of second derivative and in case n = 0, 1 it will be just zero.

Comment: That's what this shows! The second derivative of a 1st order Laguerre polynomial is zero ==> `diff(Lgr(1, x=x), x, 2)` returns a **zero**.